# I created a python and c++ node . But I cant see my nodes with rosrun command

Tags: ros-melodic, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am pretty new Ubuntu and ROS . I created a python and c++ node as you can see first and second part . But I dont see my nodes with rosrun command. I have got this nodes on my `my_robot` packages (`kaymak@kaymak-X550JX:~/catkin_ws/src/my_robot/scripts$`  and `kaymak@kaymak-X550JX:~/catkin_ws/src/my_robot/src$`) .Please help me how can I fix the problem?

---C++ Nodes ----

```
kaymak@kaymak-X550JX:~/catkin_ws/devel/lib/my_robot$ ls
node_cpp
```

---Python Nodes---

```
kaymak@kaymak-X550JX:~/catkin_ws/src/my_robot/scripts$ chmod +x my_first_node.py 
kaymak@kaymak-X550JX:~/catkin_ws/src/my_robot/scripts$ ls
my_first_node.py
```

---Error Messages---

```
kaymak@kaymak-X550JX:~$ rosrun my_robot 
Usage: rosrun [--prefix cmd] [--debug] PACKAGE EXECUTABLE [ARGS]
  rosrun will locate PACKAGE and try to find
  an executable named EXECUTABLE in the PACKAGE tree.
  If it finds it, it will run it with ARGS.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348132/i-created-a-python-and-c++-node-.-but-i-cant-see-my-nodes-with-rosrun-command./) by [Kaymak](https://answers.ros.org/users/53112/kaymak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-04-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Open bashrc file;

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Add this to the end;

```
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

Then save and quit.

If it works, you fixed it.

If it doesn't work, you can add it to the bottom of the bashrc file;

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/<user_name>/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/melodic/share
```

<user_name> -> write your own user name in this section

---

Originally posted by [jahim44229](https://answers.ros.org/users/51940/jahim44229/) with karma: 20 on 2020-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the problem . It was so easy . As I mentioned before I am new at ros . I read a lot of about the same problems . But I hadn't found the answer

The solutuion was just click 'TAB' twice rapidly after this command : kaymak@kaymak-X550JX:~$ rosrun my_robot

---

Originally posted by [Kaymak](https://answers.ros.org/users/53112/kaymak/) with karma: 13 on 2020-04-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1